# how to adjust the title in the swal modal to top left

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Hi the **swal modal** which i have developed appears to be like

[image]

I wanted the output to appear like the below image

[image]

is there anyway to reduce the size of the buttons and put the confirmation text to the top left

below is my **code**

---

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Checkbox dynamically to table cell using JavaScript</title>
    <style>
    .swal-modal {
        width: 350px;
      height: 200px
        }
        
.swal-title {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px ;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 
  align-self: top
}
.swal-text {
  font-size: 23px;
}
.swal-footer {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #E9EEF1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</body><script>
  swal({

   title:"Confimation ?",

   text:'Do you want to save',
   
  buttons: {
    confirm: {
      width:5,
    text: "Save",
    value: 'save',
    visible: true,
    className: "",
   closeModal: true
  },
  cancel: {
     width:15,
    text: "Cancel",
    value: 'cancel',
    visible: true,
    className: "",
     closeModal: true
  }
  }
})
.then((value) => {
  
  switch (value) {

    case "save":
      alert('you selected:  ' + value);
      break;
 
    case "cancel":
        alert('you selected:  ' + value);
      break;
 }
});
</script>
</html>
```

is there any way to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add customized CSS to it. like :
to align the title to top left:
add these rules to the `.swal-title`:

```css
      text-align: left;
      margin-top: 0 !important;
```

to shrink the button, add these code to the `.swal-button` :

```css
  padding: 5px;
```

also your javascript code missed a `}` and is not working, a working simple see here: http://jsfiddle.net/uxd57of2/

Comment: Thanks .I modified it a little more.now it looks better :)   
http://jsfiddle.net/4qpskgnt/

Comment: @Dodododo yeah, just showed you can make it better or fulfill your requirements by adding customized css

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional css for sweet alert popup.

```
<style>
.swal-title{
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
.swal-text {  
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
```